# Add one edge to the graph such that the graph will not be 3-colourable

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Could you guys help me solve this example?

The question is, whether it is possible to add one new edge such that the resulting graph is not 3-colourable and prove it.

[image]

I was trying to find a way to create K4 subgraph but it's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph in the drawing is bipartite:

[image]

Adding an edge to a graph increases its chromatic number by at most $1$.